# How to only subscribe to firebase collection changes

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using the firebase javascript sdk via [`@angular/fire`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) in an angular app.

Using the angularfire [`Collection#stateChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#statechanges), I thought I was *just subscribing to the state changes of a collection* (based on the description). I.e. on initial subscribe nothing would be returned. However, I'm finding that stateChanges() immediately returns everything in the collection before then continuing to return state changes.

Is there a way to *just* subscribe to future state changes and not "replay" past changes (either using the `firebase-js-sdk` directly or via `@angular/fire`)?

For example, if you already had a copy of the current state of a collection downloaded, you would not want to re-download the collection state when simply subscribing to collection updates.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, firebase does not support *only* subscribing to query changes. When you subscribe to a query, you must also download all of the related documents immediately (see issue [#1551](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1551#issuecomment-465708165) in the firebase-js-sdk repo).

This being said, as pointed out in that issue, you can fake this functionality by adding an `updatedAt` property to your documents and querying for all documents where `updatedAt > now`. This would subscribe you to just future changes.

A limitation of this work around is that Firestore only supports using an inequality filter (`>=`,`<`, etc) on a single field in a query, so using your inequality filter up on the `updatedAt` field may be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is the [stateChanges](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#statechanges) method on collections. 
 From the docs:

> Why would you use it? - The above methods return a synchronized array sorted in query order. stateChanges() emits changes as they occur rather than syncing the query order. This works well for ngrx integrations as you can build your own data structure in your reducer methods.

And a code example using `@angular/fire`:

```
this.angularFirestore
  .collection('my-collection')
  .stateChanges(['added', 'removed', updated']) // double check the state change references, these were assumed
  .pipe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the enthusiasm, but as pointed out *prominently* in my question, `stateChanges()` returns everything on initial subscription (and then subsequently returns changes objects as they occur). I agree that the `@angular/fire` docs are very misleading in their description of `stateChanges()`.

Comment: Oops, you're right I did jump the gun a little. However, that method is the only way I've been able to achieve similar functionality. I can imagine how you may want to avoid the extra reads. In your question you state that if you've already downloaded the collection, you don't want to redownload. Normally I'd think this kind of functionality would be in a singleton, could you please share more in the question about how you're using it?

Comment: I went into the firebase-js-sdk some more and it doesn't look like it's possible to do what I'm trying to do. I created a [feature request in the sdk repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1551) that goes into more detail about possible use cases. The problem appears to be that, at the moment, `QuerySnapshot#docChanges` returns the entire query the first time its invoked. There doesn't appear to be an option to turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is the one I used for my similar case.
I have users, groups, and requests of a users in a group.

On login, I get the needed data (all data at a glance).

But for a logged in user, I need to subscribe any insertion, deletion, or edition of the requests of the group (not only updated-at..).

So I created a collection of changed requests. (groupRequestsChanged)

I have subscribed to

```
collection('groupRequestsChanged').doc(group-id-here...).valueChanged().subscribe()
```

This approach is helpful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this party, but I handle this by first getting as many documents as i want to display (pagination), and then subscribe to changes using `stateChanges`. So first I do something like

```
public displayedMessages: Array<any>;
this.db.collection('messages').ref.limitToLast(100).get().then(result => {
  // display the result, 
  this.displayedMessages = result;

  //then watch changes:
  this.db.collection('messages').stateChanges().pipe(
    skip(1),
    map(changes => {
      changes.forEach(itemDoc => {
        if (itemDoc.type == 'added') {
          this.displayedMessages.push(item);
        } else if (itemDoc.type == 'modified') {
          // find the message in displayedMessages and update the data
        } else if (itemDoc.type == 'removed') {
          // find the index and splice it. 
        }
      })
    })
  )
})
```

The key here is `skip(1)` from rxjs. It skips the first emitted value, which is the whole collection. You just got the whole thing with `get`, so you dont need the first emission of `stateChanges`. So now every time that collection is changed, you only get the changes.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Though I should have also mentioned in my question that cost is a concern. One of the reasons that I just want to get the changes is to avoid the cost (both performance and money) of grabbing the whole collection initially. For this reason `skip(1)` isn't a good option for me, but maybe it will be for others.